# iOS textview auto size in a scroll view (no textview's scroll bar)

Tags: ios, scroll, textview, size, scrollview

I have a view with a scrollview, title, subtitle, image and a description.
like this:

[image: storyboard view controller elements]

I will show some text downloaded from my server (it could be few lines, or many lines) in a the descriptionTextview. I will scroll all the view, not only the texview because most part of the view is busy by the other elements.
like this:

[image: storyboard view controller]

I unchecked "scrolling enable" from the textView and I change size attributes to "Freeform" in the View Controller attributes inspector.
Since I add textView to my viewController the scrollView doesn't scroll.
How can I display all the text of the textview in a scroll view?

I tried to add these lines in the `viewDidLoad` for change programmatically size of the textview and the scrollview, but it didn't work.

```
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

CGRect frame = self.descriptionTextView.frame;
frame.size.height = self.descriptionTextView.contentSize.height;
self.descriptionTextView.frame = frame;

[self.scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320,480+self.descriptionTextView.frame.size.height))];
NSLog(@"tv height %f", self.descriptionTextView.frame.size.height);
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**:

- This viewController has a NavigationController.
- The previous ViewController is one item of TabBarViewController. This Tab has CustomCell.
- From clicking on the cell it shows this View with scrollView (Web Detail View Controller).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but the attribute `animation:YES` of `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myNextViewController animated:`**YES**`];` of **Navigation Controller** was the problem!!!!!

I delete storyboard's segue and I write `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myNextViewController animated:NO];` and now IT WORK!!!

If someone can give me an explanation of that, would be great.
Thanks

EDIT: need textview height > scrollview height, set 10000 in storyboard:

[image: static height of textView]

**EDIT 2:** problem persist! I call `self.myTextView.text = @"someStringText"` and I can see all the text but the view is scrolling very long: like 10.000! So this method doesn't programmatically set height :( unchecked right answer. Can anyone please answer the question?

thank you

**EDIT 3: THE SOLUTION** finally, I think I got the solution: in `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;` I set text programmatically with `self.descriptionTextView.text = content.text; //long long text`, after them I call `[self textViewDidChange:self.descriptionTextView];`

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    //VERY IMPORTANT: without this, user can scroll scrollView and textview!
    [textView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
```

In storyboard checkbox `use Autolayout` is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your scrollview contentsize method to viewdidappear not viewdidload

Comment: tried, nothig changed: only textview is scrolling :( (even it hasn't `scrolling enable` checked!!!) thanks for your reply.

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing your scrollview in your storyboard or xib file correctly? I have created a test project with the code you uploaded previously, seems to be working

Comment: Yes. I use Storyboard, I create an outlet in .h file of my viewController. I use this outlet..

Comment: You're right, but the problem is not solved: I create a new project, sigle view with scrollView, one Label, one TextView. I make outlet of scrollView (myScrollView), outlet of TextView (myTextView), and I pasted my code with the correct name of outlet in the `viewDidAppear` method. It works!!! I've done the same this in my main project but it doesn't works!!!!! See my edit, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hmm interesting, my only guess is that maybe the uitabbarcontroller or uinavigationcontroller is conflicting with the userinteraction somehow. Have you tried presenting the webDetailViewController modally as a test instead of creating a uinavigationcontroller? I can have a look at the project for you if you want. You can email me it over.

Comment: Sorry, I can't send you the project :( Yes, very misteryous: in the dummy project where the scroll works, I add navigation controller and tab bar controller. I put the viewController with the scrollview in the TabbarController, [like a tab](http://s13.postimg.org/3z0zmtpzb/Schermata_2013_12_05_alle_12_03_01.png), and it works!!!  In my opinion there is somthings wrong with segue..Thanks for your help

Comment: +1 for teach me to the solution: see my answer. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you're using a text view instead of a label? Since a text view is a scroll view, and having a scroll view inside a scroll view is problematic, could you not easily solve the problem by using a UILabel and setting the number of lines to 0 so it grows to fit your content?

(Sorry, I don't have a high enough rep to add this as a comment.)

Comment: Yes, I download text from server, I can't know how much lines there are: could be 2 lines, 10, or 40... (No problem, I have your same problem for comment...)

Comment: Even in that case, I'd still try to use a UILabel (simply set the number of lines to 0).

Comment: I tried: error: It shows text in only one line and it gives: `Illegal Configuration: Interface Builder does not support UILabel sizes larger than 10,000 by 10,000.`. Thank you